# ng-model making razor model's value blank

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a razor form with combination of angularjs and i am sending a razor model to my form with all the data.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.coupon_code, new { ng_model = "coupon_code", ng_change = "ValidateCoupon()", placeholder = "Coupon Code*", ng_init = "coupon_code=myForm.coupon_code)" })
```

My `@Model.coupon_code` has value in it but ng-model is making it blank and textbox becomes blank.When i remove ng-model textbox takes shows razor value.

Tried using data_ng_model too, but din't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are missed single quotes(''),

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.coupon_code, new { ng_model = "coupon_code", ng_change = "ValidateCoupon()", placeholder = "Coupon Code*", ng_init = "coupon_code='myForm.coupon_code'" })
```

For dynamic value binding ,

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.coupon_code, new { ng_model = "coupon_code", ng_change = "ValidateCoupon()", placeholder = "Coupon Code*", ng_init = "coupon_code='" + Model.coupon_code + "'" })
```